# Checking generic types in an Action delegate callback

Tags: c#, generics, callback, delegates, action

So here is the code,

```
public void DoSomething<T>(string key, Action<T> callback)
{
    Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

    if (typeParameterType.Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
        callback("my string response");
    }
    if (typeParameterType.Equals(typeof(int)))
    {
        callback(1); // my int response
    }
    // etc...
}
```

However, I'm getting errors... I'm new to all the C# generic and delegate stuff.

The error I'm getting is,

```
Error   1   Delegate 'System.Action<T>' has some invalid arguments
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'T'
```

For me its important to create beautiful and useful methods that are easy and idiomatic.

SO I'd love to implement the above example like this,

```
int total = 0;
DoSomething<int>("doesn't matter", x => {
    total = 10 + x; // i can do this because x is an INT!!! (:
});

string message = "This message is almost ";
DoSomething<int>("doesn't matter", x => {
    message = "finished!!!"; // i can do this because x is an STRING!!! (:
});
```

But I'm stuck... please help!

===============================================================================

As dasblinkenlight pointed out,

Overloading is the cleanest most compiler friendly approach... My API now looks like,

```
DoSomething("doesn't matter", new Action<string>(x => {
    message = "finished!!!"; // i can do this because x is an STRING!!! (:
}));
```

Which is small price to pay and easier to understand.

Thanks for the answer (:

===============================================================================

Doing some more research, I can really clean it up by doing the following;

```
DoSomething("doesn't matter", (string x) => {
    message = "finished!!!"; // i can do this because x is an STRING!!! (:
});
```

Notice this: **(string x)**

Now the compiler knows! Very cool huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific types such as `int` and `string` cannot be cast to `T`, but `object` can be. This should work:

```
if (typeParameterType.Equals(typeof(string)))
{
    callback((T)((object)"my string response"));
}
if (typeParameterType.Equals(typeof(int)))
{
    callback((T)((object)1)); // my int response
}
```

However, it's a little strange that you need to do this in the first place: rather than jumping through hoops with generics, you could deal with the problem more gracefully with multiple methods:

```
public void DoSomething(string key, Action<int> callback) {
    callback(1);
}
public void DoSomething(string key, Action<string> callback) {
    callback("my string response");
}
```

Now you can call these methods like this:

```
DoSomething("hello", new Action<int>(x => Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", x)));
DoSomething("world", new Action<string>(x => Console.WriteLine("str: {0}", x)));
```

or like this:

```
DoSomething("hello", (int x) => Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", x));
DoSomething("world", (string x) => Console.WriteLine("str: {0}", x));
```

Comment: Then I get this:  Error 1 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.DoSomething(string, System.Action<int>)' and 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.DoSomething(string, System.Action<string>)'

Comment: @Erik5388 Well, if you must support `object` or subclasses the second trick isn't going to work. Did the first trick (cast to object) work?

Comment: because its being used like:            c.DoSomething("whatever", x =>
            {
                 // do stuff with x as a type
            });

Comment: @Erik5388 Since the caller knows the type, you might as well give the overloads two separate names - see the edit.

Comment: Your first trick works... The second one doesn't feel clean though

Comment: @Erik5388 The second one cleans up the `DoSomething` quite a bit, because the `if`/`then`/`else` dispatch based on the run-time type is gone. If the program compiles, there's not going to be a situation when a type is passed to `DoSomething` that the method does not know how to service: the program wouldn't compile then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940170/checking-generic-types-in-an-action-delegate-callback/18940267#18940267   <-- Does that one fall into the same pits as your first trick?

Comment: @Erik5388 Absolutely: it uses generics where no generics are necessary, and postpones the decision on argument types until runtime when it is possible to make the checks at compile time.

Comment: I appreciate the awareness.. Is there ANY way I can achieve this simplistic (one method does all) request?

I'd hate to do: DoSomethingString or DoSomethingInt32

Comment: Maybe when I told you about the ambitiousness between the methods.. perhaps it is better to in fact do the "overloads" but force users to define ACTION types before the method calls... This way the compiler knows what types are in the parameter.

Comment: @Erik5388 Yes, that should work. You can also add an explicit cast to your actions, making sure that the appropriate overload gets selected.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your answer one last time, to show everyone what you came up with to solve this approach (proper stackoverflowing, haha)... Updated in regards to yours and my last comment.

Comment: Hey check out the bottom part of the question... I updated it,

Comment: DoSomething("doesn't matter", (string x) => {
        message = "finished!!!";
});

See the (string x), therefore not needed to create new Action instance

Comment: @Erik5388 Pretty cool! You could also suggest an edit to an answer - community promptly approves them these days.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the callback type:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(string key, Action<T> callback)
{
    var action1 = callback as Action<string>;
    if (action1 != null)
    {
        action1("my string response");
        return;
    }

    var action2 = callback as Action<int>;
    if (action2 != null)
    {
        action2(1); // my int response
        return;
    }
    // etc...
}
```